# Ubuntu Freezing upon Ubuntu logo on installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, nvidia, virtualbox

UPDATE:

I did install Ubuntu, just had to disable fast boot. But now i can boot it like this:

Open PC(booting windows 8.1 by default), go to PC settings, advanced recovery, restart. Troubleshoot, boot from USB.

Now, i don't have a USB in my PC but when i choose this , there is an Ubuntu option. When i click it, Ubuntu start booting. Is there any chance i can choose which one to boot when my PC starts?

---

I recently bought a new computer(MSI, Intel Core i7, with nvidia gtx950m).
The PC had by default windows 8.1.

So in my college I need to have Ubuntu installed in my PC for Labs and stuff.
I started by using it with Vbox and for a month or so it didn't cause any problems. Now it just causes BlueScreen to my PC every time I open Ubuntu from VB (machine_check_exception).

I tried making a dualboot, followed step-by-step the articles, but I get to this problem every time.

After booting from USB the Ubuntu installation menu comes up, having 4 choices.

1. Try Ubuntu without installing
2. Install Ubuntu
3. OEM install (for manufacturers)
4. disk *something I don't remember*

So I have tried the first 3 option and here is what I get.

When choosing the option 1, I see the Ubuntu desktop for 5-6 seconds, then a black screen comes out and a console starts writing on its own.

Choosing option 2 and 3 is exactly the same. After choosing it the Ubuntu logo comes up and then it just freezes there for hours. Have searched for same problems but they were not found.

Comment: Do you want to install Ubuntu as dual boot, or do you want to fix the Virtual Box issue?

Comment: i would prefer to dualboot

Comment: Failure of an Ubuntu installation CD can have many reasons, from a corrupt installation CD to a hardware issue or incompatibiliy. Because you say you started to have issues with your host Windows when opening a VM it makes me believe it may come from your hardware (RAM?). Any chance to read the output of presumably error messages *"black screen comes out and a console starts writing on its own"*? These may point in the right directions.

Answer (score 1):

As you said in your comment you want to install Ubuntu as a dual boot solution.

1. Boot into Windows installation and **disable hibernation** and **Fast Boot**.  To disable hibernation open a **command prompt as administrator** and execute :

   ```
   powercfg /h off
   ```

   To disable Fast Boot open **Control Panel** (the old version - not the modern design),
   select the **Energy Settings**, enable **show hidden settings** and **uncheck Fast Boot**.
2. Boot from your Ubuntu installation media - highlight **Try Ubuntu without installing**.
   Press "**e**" and add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line. Then press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.
3. Start the installation - choose **Something else** - select the partition for Ubuntu to install.
4. When finished installation boot into BIOS and select Ubuntu to be the default system to boot.
5. After having completed all these steps : reboot ...
6. Highlight the **Ubuntu entry** in the **GRUB menu** and add **nouveau.modeset=0** to the end of the linux line.
   (the same procedure as you did  before: Press "**e**" - **add the parameter** - then press **F10** to boot)
7. The first thing you should do now is to install **NVIDIA** graphics **drivers** and **Optimus** in Ubuntu !

Comment: Thank you. As you can see in the update i managed to install Ubuntu followed by these errors...

1) Sometimes my PC closes while Ubuntu are running. I'm sure that's because i didn't install the nvidia drivers. BUT!

2) Every time i try to install NVIDIA driver, my PC keeps closing.

What do you suggest?